# Can I wire light sockets with 12 gauge wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a dedicated 20A breaker with 12 gauge wire running to my shed.  I have been installing outlets where I need that in my next step is to put in some light sockets.

I made them myself out of PVC and a light socket from Home Depot.

The light socket wires are very skinny. Can I connect them to my 12gauge wire that I have going throughout the rest of the shed? Do I have to buy a specific light socket?

Answer (score 2):

As an electrician I always like to see fixtures with a UL Listing, but the wire size on your socket is used since it assumes a certain maximum wattage (amperage) lamp and therefore is allowed by the manufacturer. You can connect it up to a #12 wire on a 20A circuit since that is greater than the intended load of the lamp.

If you're interested that's covered in Article 402 in the NEC.

Comment: Also some discussion in the tap rules 240.21.